# Precision Recall Curves in R

Tags: r, graph, precision, precision-recall

Can someone help me understand the "threshold" (i.e. the color gradient) in this precision recall curve (produced in R)?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c64Tw.jpg

R code:

```
library(PRROC)
 x <-rnorm(1000)
 y <-rnorm(1000,-1) 
pr <- pr.curve(x,y, curve=TRUE)
 plot(pr)
```

Why does the threshold go from -3 to 3? Doesn't the threshold have to be between 0 and 1? Does anyone know how to fix this (produce a threshold between 0 and 1)?

Thanks!

source: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/PRROC/PRROC.pdf

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about interpreting the results from various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there. Also make sure to use `set.seed()` with random numbers so your results are reproducible. I'm guessing the threshold value is on the scale of your observed data. Not sure why you were expecting 0-1 range here. You don't seem to be using probabilities at all here.

Comment: The gradient colour scale corresponds to the range of your `x` and `y` values (i.e. `range(c(x, y))`); in your case, the randomly generated values are somewhere between -4 and 3 (the exact values depend on the random number generator seed). Compare this with e.g. `plot(pr.curve(1:10, 1:10, curve = TRUE))` which will produce a gradient colour scale between 1 and 10. Why do you think the numbers should be between 0 and 1?

Comment: Is it possible to produce a graph like this: https://machinelearning-blog.com/2018/04/03/evaluation-metrics-for-classification/ ?

Comment: @stats555 The figure shows the recall/precision trade-off as a function of different (classifier) thresholds. You don't show any code/data that involves a classification problem. Can you please edit your post to include more details/code & context. It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: On the same track with @MauritsEvers, the scale of color bar is indicative so as to achieve rich color range palette. Red is close to 0 theif P=N then Precision = 0.5 (FP = N) while purple is close to 1 Precision = 0.5 since FP = 0

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear to me what you're trying to do; the figure you link to in the comments shows the precision/recall as a function of varying threshold parameters of a classifier, but you don't show code involving any classification problem.

Let's use the `iris` data set and construct a simple binary classification problem; to do so, we first remove all data for `Species == "setosa"`.

```r
data <- subset(iris, Species %in% c("versicolor", "virginica"))
data <- droplevels(data)
```

We then use a simple SVM with a Gaussian (radial) kernel for our classifier. In this case we have only one parameter `gamma`. We determine the precision/recall of our classifier for changing values of `gamma` and plot the results

```r
library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)

gamma <- 10^(seq(-3, 2, by = 0.1))
df <- map_dfr(
    cost,
    function(param)
        svm(Species ~ ., data = data, gamma = param, kernel = "radial") %>%
            predict() %>%
            confusionMatrix(data$Species, mode = "prec_recall") %>%
            pluck("byClass") %>%
            enframe() %>%
            filter(name %in% c("Precision", "Recall")) %>%
            mutate(gamma_param = param))

ggplot(df, aes(gamma_param, value, colour = name)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_x_log10() +
    expand_limits(y = c(0, 1)) + 
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Note that the parameter(s) (and the values it/they take) depend(s) on your classifier; in this simple case you only have one single tunable parameter.

PS. I have used `ggplot` and other `tidyverse` functions out of habit & convenience; you can do something similar in base R as well.